# How do I search through a long list of attributes and match it to fontawesome icon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, font-awesome

I have a `PropertyFeatureOption` model, that has data that looks like this:

```
+-----+-------------------------+--------+----------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id  | name                    | shared | exterior | amenity | created_at              | updated_at              |
+-----+-------------------------+--------+----------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 101 | Dining Room             | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC |
| 102 | Security                | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC |
| 103 | Common Area             | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC |
| 104 | Swimming Pool           | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC |
| 105 | Automatic Gate          | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC |
| 106 | Panic Button            | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC |
| 107 | Car Port                | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC |
| 108 | Electric Generator      | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC |
| 109 | Water Pump              | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC |
| 110 | Air Conditioning        | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC |
| 111 | Cable                   | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC |
| 112 | Kitchen                 | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC |
| 113 | Security Guard          | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:36 UTC |
| 114 | Family Room             | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC |
| 115 | Other Room              | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC |
| 116 | Patio                   | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC |
| 117 | Electronic Security     | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC |
| 118 | Garage                  | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC |
| 119 | Dish                    | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC |
| 120 | Furnished               | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC |
| 121 | Living Room             | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC |
| 122 | Canteen                 | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC |
| 123 | Telephone Lines         | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:37 UTC |
| 124 | Restroom                | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:38 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:38 UTC |
| 125 | Powder Room             | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:38 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:38 UTC |
| 126 | Den/Study               | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:38 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:38 UTC |
| 127 | Water Tank              | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:38 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:38 UTC |
| 128 | Partitions              | false  | false    | false   | 2014-01-30 00:07:39 UTC | 2014-01-30 00:07:39 UTC |
| 129 | Fully Fenced            | false  | false    | false   | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC |
| 130 | Garden Area             | false  | false    | false   | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC |
| 131 | Ceiling Fans            | false  | false    | false   | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC |
| 132 | Grilled                 | false  | false    | false   | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC |
| 133 | Kitchen Built-in(s)     | false  | false    | false   | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC |
| 134 | Main Level Entry        | false  | false    | false   | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC |
| 135 | Unfurnished             | false  | false    | false   | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC |
| 136 | Barn                    | false  | false    | false   | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC | 2014-02-27 06:31:34 UTC |
```

It has 117 records in total.

What I am trying to do is on a `Property#Show` page, depending on the presence of any of these on the `property` object I am viewing, I would like to show the font-awesome icons related to these entries.

So, basically I need to hardcode the link between the different names of these records, and the various font-awesome icons.

For example, if a `property` has a `property_feature_option.name.eql? "Car Port"` (i.e. `ID=107` in that table above), I would want to show `fa fa-car`. There can be many mappings of `property_feature_options` to font-awesome icon names.

E.g. `Panic Button, Security Guard & Electronic Security` can go to `fa fa-bullhorn` (just an example).

How do I approach this? Not quite sure about where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is what @iGian says, put those in a hash. To keep things tidy, you should put them into a separate namespace:

```
module FeatureIconizer
  module_function

  ICONS = {
    'Car Port' => 'fa-car',
    'Panic Button' => 'fa-bullhorn',
    'Security Guard' => 'fa-bullhorn',
    ...
  }

  DEFAULT = 'fa-house'

  def icon_class(feature)
    'fa ' + ICONS.fetch(feature.name, DEFAULT)
  end
end
```

Another option, as you have defined your features in DB, is to add the icon in DB too. This way you don't need a deploy to change one icon.

Comment: Interesting, you mean add a column to that table for `Icon Name` and then just query that column whenever an Property Feature is queried? That's an intriguing alternative.

Comment: yes. It mainly depends on whether you consider the icon mapping as part of your data, and on your ability not to mess too much with wrong SQL.

Comment: Yeah this is quite an elegant solution and one which I prefer. It works for this particular app.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do something like this, I defined a pure Ruby class just to show, but you can adjust for Rails.

```
class PropertyFeatureOption
  attr_reader :name

  ICON_MAP  = { "fa fa-car" => ["Car Port"], "fa fa-bullhorn" => ["Panic Button", "Security Guard",  "Electronic Security"] }.freeze

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def icon
    icon = ICON_MAP.select { |k, v| v.include? name }.keys.first || "fa fa-whathever"
    icon.to_s
  end

end

property_feature_option = PropertyFeatureOption.new("Panic Button")
property_feature_option.icon #=> "fa fa-bullhorn"

property_feature_option = PropertyFeatureOption.new("Not in list")
property_feature_option.icon #=> "fa fa-whathever"
```

Comment: You seem to be using the hash backwards. Hashes are designed to be looked up, so wouldn't it make more sense to switch the keys and values, then you can look them up with simply `ICON_MAP[name]`?

Comment: @DaveSlutzkin, yes you are right, but I wanted to keep simple the ICON_MAP Hash, since it is hardcoded.

Comment: I like this suggestion, but I prefer @rewritten's answer a bit more for my particular situation. Thanks for the suggestion though!